# React Native - Background Image should scroll with the Text

Tags: react-native

I have the background transparent image (the light blue in the screenshot). The problem is when I type something in the textbox a vertical scroll comes up and the form moves a little bit up. Is it possible that the background moves with the scroll as well?

#1 - in the screenshot is the form that moves

#2 - is the background image

**Here is the code**

```
<Container style={styles.container}>    
       <ImageBackground source={loginbackground}  style={{width: '100%',height:'100%' }}>
         <Content> 
          <View style={{marginTop:margint,paddingLeft:30,paddingRight:30}}>           
             
               <View style={{marginTop:10}}>
                <Item style={{backgroundColor:'rgb(149,197,69)',borderRadius:8,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'rgb(117,170,70)'}}>               
                 <Image source={emailicon} style={{height:20,width:20,marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}}/>
                 <Input placeholder="Email" value={this.state.username} onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({ username: text }) }  placeholderTextColor="rgb(240,240,240)" />
               </Item>
              </View>
               <View style={{marginTop:15}}>
                <Item style={{backgroundColor:'rgb(149,197,69)',borderRadius:8,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'rgb(117,170,70)'}}>               
                 <Image source={passwordicon} style={{height:20,width:20,marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}}/>
                 <Input placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} value={this.state.Password} onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({ Password: text }) }   placeholderTextColor="rgb(240,240,240)" />
               </Item>
              </View>
              {this.state.Loading==true?
               <ActivityIndicator
          animating={true}
          style={styles.indicator} />
              :
              <View>
              <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',marginTop:15}}>
              <View style={{width:'13%',justifyContent:'center'}}>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._toggleRememberme()}>
                <Image source={this.state.isrememberme?checkboxcheck:checkboxuncheck} style={{width:28,height:28}}/>
               </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{width:'41%',justifyContent:'center'}}>
               <Text onPress={() => this._toggleRememberme()} style={{fontSize:17,color:'rgb(56,56,56)'}} >Remember me</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{width:'46%',justifyContent:'center'}}>
               <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("forgotpass")} style={{textAlign:'right', fontSize:17,color:'rgb(56,56,56)'}} >Forgot password?</Text>
              </View>
              </View>   
                <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("signup")} style={{textAlign:'center', textDecorationLine:'underline', fontSize:17,color:'rgb(56,56,56)',marginTop:15}} >Create an Account</Text>             
                <Button onPress={() => this.signin()} block style={{backgroundColor:'rgb(107,29,43)', marginTop:15,height:50, borderRadius:8,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'rgb(117,170,70)'}}>
                 <Text style={{color:'#fff',fontSize:19}}>Login</Text>
                </Button>   
                                
             </View>
              }
          </View>
         </Content>     
         </ImageBackground>
      </Container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to clairify, you would like for the form to appear fixed above the image background, and for the form and image background to move together as you scroll. So, currently your background is fixed, but the form is above and scrolls independently of the background?

I just want to make sure I have your question correct :)

I think when you use ImageBackground it will always behave in this way, hence the "background". If you want the form to move with the image you could try to position the form with "absolute" position on top of a regular Image component. You might want to try using react-native-elements or react-native-paper as they have Card and Surface components which can help to achieve this behaviour.

I realize this isn't a very definitive answer but I hope it helps in some way. Also you might want to just check any style props of the components which you have used as well as reviewing the documentation on ImageBackground. https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

My apologies that I couldn't give you a better answer.

Comment: Both the image and text should scroll together, so not sure if not ImageBackground, what should I use?